# How to get list of ActiveStorage attributes (attachment names)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

For example I have model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_one_attached :diploma

  has_many_attached :photos
  has_many_attached :files
end
```

How to get lists of attachments names for some model (separately for `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached`)?

`[:avatar, :diploma]` and `[:photos, :files]` in this case.

Comment: So given an arbitrary model class `M`, you want to know the `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached` names for `M`?

Comment: @muistooshort, yes. Separately for `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution that doesn't depend on naming conventions and will give you exactly what you need based on Rails own internals:

- for `has_one_attached`

```rb
User
  .reflect_on_all_attachments
  .filter { |association| association.instance_of? ActiveStorage::Reflection::HasOneAttachedReflection }
  .map(&:name)
```

- for `has_many_attached`

```rb
User
  .reflect_on_all_attachments
  .filter { |association| association.instance_of? ActiveStorage::Reflection::HasManyAttachedReflection }
  .map(&:name)
```

Comment: `User.reflect_on_all_attachments.filter_map { |association| association.name if association.instance_of?(ActiveStorage::Reflection::HasOneAttachedReflection) }` and `User.reflect_on_all_attachments.filter_map { |association| association.name if association.instance_of?(ActiveStorage::Reflection::HasManyAttachedReflection) }`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a straightforward way, bud this should workaround (for already stored records):

```
ActiveStorage::Attachment.distinct.pluck(:record_type).map(&:underscore)
```

---

Starting from a model, this is a raw idea to be refined:

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map { |e| e.name.to_s.split("_") }.select { |e| e.last == "attachments" }
User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).map { |e| e.name.to_s.split("_") }.select { |e| e.last == "attachment" }
```

Note `== "attachments"` and `== "attachment"`

Comment: Thanks, it is also helpful. But unfortunately, I need general list, not only stored records

Comment: @mechnicov, please, check if my edit gives you an hint

Comment: Good hint! But don't need use `split('_')` because name can include `_`. Something like `User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map { |reflection| reflection.name.to_s }.select { |name| name.match?(/_attachments/) }.map { |name| name.chomp('_attachments').to_sym }`.

Answer (score 1):

@iGian gave a great idea, but there is a problem in it.

If the attachment name contains the underscore(s), it will lead to an incorrect result.

So my solution is:

- for `has_many_attached`

```
User.
  reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).
  map { |reflection| reflection.name.to_s }.
  select { |name| name.match?(/_attachments/) }.
  map { |name| name.chomp('_attachments').to_sym }

#=> [:photos, :files]
```

- for `has_one_attached`

```
User.
  reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).
  map { |reflection| reflection.name.to_s }.
  select { |name| name.match?(/_attachment/) }.
  map { |name| name.chomp('_attachment').to_sym }

#=> [:avatar, :diploma]
```